# In classical Chinese, does 從 always imply the follower is lower in rank?

Tags: meaning, classical-chinese, verbs

When 從 in Classical Chinese means "to follow", literally as in "John followed Peter to the park," does the subject (the follower) necessarily refer to someone who is lower in rank than whoever the object (the followed) refers to?

Do you know of any examples where this use of 從 does not require a subject that refers to someone lower in rank?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the book “殷周金文集成”, the entry [04030](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=04340&jgwfl=),

my best understanding of 从 in the 5th column:

engaged in (从) the commanding (司) [of] the royal court (王家), outside and inside (外內)

the structure of “从司” is similar to “從事”, or “從政”; that “从” means “engaged in, enter, become”. it does not have the meaning of “follow” here.

[image]

[image]

edited. if 從 (u+5f9e) is allowed, in lieu of 从 (u+4ece); then, in the book of rites (禮記), the chapter 曾子問 has the text:

> 孔子曰・大宰・大宗・從大祝而告於禰

in the same book, the chapter 曲禮下:

> 天子建天官・先六大・曰大宰・大宗・大史・大祝・大士・大卜・典司六典

roughly, it means:

> Confucius said, 'The Grand minister and the Grand master of the ancestral temple will follow the Grand officer of prayer, and announce the fact before the spirit tablet (of the deceased ruler)

that, the grand minister (大宰), the grand master of the ancestral temple (大宗) were the no 1 & no 2 in 周 dynasty

the grand  officer of prayer (大祝) is the no 4

so, under specified circumstance, the no1 & no2 official would follow (**從**) a lower ranking official (the no4) to a particular place.

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=59684

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=9558

[image]

edited again.

> Are there any cases where the object of 從 did not display such superiority or any superiority altogether?

well, in the book 莊子, chapter 德充符:

> 魯有兀者王駘，**從**之遊者，與仲尼相若

roughly, it means:

> In Lu there was a Wang Tai who had lost both his feet; while his disciples who **followed** and went about with him, were as numerous as those of confucius.

that, in ancient time, disabled persons were treated as inferior. in this case, mr 王’s disciples were numerous, that, we ought to assume that most, if not all of them are able-bodied.

so, the “從” in here does not infer superiority.

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=2748

another case is in the same book, chapter 達生:

> 孔子觀於呂梁，縣水三十仞，流沫四十里，黿鼉魚龞之所不能游也。見一丈夫游之，以為有苦而欲死也，使弟子並流而拯之。數百步而出，被髮行歌而游於塘下。孔子**從**而問焉

roughly, it means:

> Confucius was looking at the cataract near the gorge of Lu, which fell a height of 240 cubits, and the spray of which floated a distance of forty li (producing a turbulence) in which no tortoise, gavial, fish, or turtle could play. He saw, however, an old man swimming about in it, as if he had sustained some great calamity, and wished to end his life. Confucius made his disciples hasten along the stream to rescue the man; and by the time they had gone several hundred paces, he was walking along singing, with his hair dishevelled, and enjoying himself at the foot of the embankment. Confucius **followed** and asked him

i think this example is clear, that the “從” doesn’t not display any superiority.

have fun :)

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=2847#s10042177

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111840/discussion-on-answer-by--in-classical-chinese-does--always-imply-the-follo).

Answer (score -2):

In modern chinese, It's rare to use 從 as a verb to represent "follow someone to a place".

So if you mean "John followed Peter to the park", you can use 跟著 隨著. John 跟著/隨著 Peter
to the park.

從 has several extended meanings which comes from FOLLOW (phyically to logically).

e.g.

隨從 - entourage

服從 聽從 順從 - obey, comply with...

從軍 - Join the Military, 從政 - engage in politics, 從事 - engaged in, work as, do (你從事的工作是甚麼？)

從2020年 - since 2020, 從現在開始 - from now on.

[Here](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E5%BE%9E&search=%E5%BE%9E) for more information about 從，All explaintions are userful and very commonly used in daily conversation.

Comment: I'm asking about 從 in the partiular sense I'm interested in in Classical Chinese, not Mandarin.